# How to stop toggling classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is how I started toggling classes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $('.blinkClass').toggleClass('blink');
    }, 500);  
});
```

How can I stop toggling these classes?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the timer returned from `setInterval` to a variable which you can then use in a call to `clearInterval()`:

```
var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    $('.blinkClass').toggleClass('blink');
}, 500);  

// later on, in a code block within scope of the above variable... 
clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: thanks :) it is working

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myVar  = window.setInterval(function() {
        $('.blinkClass').toggleClass('blink');
    }, 500); 

    //when you want     
    myStopFunction(myVar)
});

function myStopFunction(par) {
    clearInterval(par);
}
```

See more info at

[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

[clearinterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Comment: I wouldn't use W3Schools, ever. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is better in every way; more reliable, more accurate and more often updated.

Comment: What is the point of using a separate function which actually does nothing.

Comment: It can be called multiple times if there are other setInterval